# Is this Ruby syntax or is it a DSL and how can I learn Ruby syntax or Rails DSL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dsl

For example here is some code in the routes.rb file

```rb
match 'products/:id' => 'products#show', via: :get
```

I would think match is a method without parens, so that is something I am used to.  Then the match method takes two arguments. But is

```rb
'products/:id' => 'products#show'
```

supposed to be an implied hash?  I can't create a hash using no braces like this seems to be doing here

```rb
my_hash = 'p' => 'x'
```

Then the last piece doesn't work in my irb substituting the values but keeping the structure.

I know how to read the docs and just copy paste and sub out values for what I need and make things work, but I want to understand the syntax so that I can just write the code without having to feel like it is all arbitrary and needing the docs to show me exactly what to type.

Comment: (Ruby) DSLs are always Ruby syntax because they are written in Ruby. Ruby is flexible but it doesn’t allow you to alter or extend the syntax itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the hash, it is, indeed, a hash. When creating a new hash, Ruby expects it to be defined within curly braces (`{}`). However, it allows it to be declared without braces when passing it as an argument to a method (when it is the last argument). Same thing happens with `via: :get`.

You can read more about it [here](https://skorks.com/2009/08/more-advanced-ruby-method-arguments-hashes-and-blocks/#hashes-as-the-last-argument).

Comment: That works. Thanks.  The only last puzzle is why did the hash use two different styles? The first key/value of the hash uses the => syntax/style and then the second one used the colon style.  Why switch it up like that?

Comment: @NathanPena one addition to the answer `via: :get` is a `Hash` in this case; however, that style can also be used keyword arguments, which differ from a `Hash`. Also in regards to "style" of `Hash`, ruby 1.9 introduced the `key: value` syntax before that "hash rocket" syntax was the only way to write a literal `Hash`. This syntax still exists because a `Hash` key can be anything but `key: value` can only be used when `key` is a symbol....

Comment: ...For instance if the key is an `Array` then `{[1,2,3] => 6}` or more commonly if the key is a variable `{x => 6}`. Here if the local variable `x` represents the value `"Nathan"` then the `Hash` is `{"Nathan" => 6}` however if we tried to express this as `{x: 6}` then the `Hash` would be `{:x => 6}` because this syntax indicates that the key is the `Symbol` `:x`. The hash rocket syntax is used in the first case because `'products/:id'` is a `String` and while you could represent this as a `Symbol` e.g. `:'products/:id'` data access becomes much more awkward so we leave the key as a String.